# Change the style or background of a cell in Dominate table (Python)

Tags: python, html, dominate

Here's a sample from my csv file (imagine that the xxxx.img are actually http://my.website.me/xxxx.img)

```
LHS_itemname,LHS_img, LHS_color, RHS_itemname, RHS_img, RHS_color 
backpack,    bck.img, blue     , lunchbox,     lch.img, blue
backpack,    bck.img, green    , lunchbox,     lch.img, blue
```

I want to display this csv as an HTML table where each image url can be grabbed from the web using the web url and displayed inside the table. And if the LHS_color is the same as the RHS_color, I want that row in the table to have a grey background.

Here's what I have so far using the `dominate` package in Python:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import csv
import urllib
import re
import glob
import numpy as np
from dominate import document
from dominate.tags import *
import dominate
```

Set names for the input csv and output html (call them inFileName, and outFileName)

```
f = open(inFileName, 'rb')  # Path to csv file
reader = csv.reader(f)
header = ['LHS_itemname','LHS_img', 'LHS_color', 'RHS_itemname', 'RHS_img', 'RHS_color']
with document(title='ItemsBoughtTogether') as doc:
h1('ItemsBoughtTogether', align = 'Center')
with table(border='1').add(tbody()):

    l = thead().add(tr())
    for col in header:
        print col
        l += td(p(b(str(col))))

    l = thead().add(tr())
    for row in reader:
        l = tr()
        l += td(p(row[0], ALIGN='Center'))
        l += td(p(row[1], ALIGN='Center'))
        l += td(div(img(src=row[2]), _class='photo', ALIGN='Center')) # img LHS
        l += td(p(row[3], ALIGN='Center'))
        l += td(p(row[4], ALIGN='Center'))
        l += td(div(img(src=row[6]), _class='photo', ALIGN='Center')) # img RHS
        if row[2] == row[5]: {background-color:'grey'}
```

This last `if` statement is what I don't know how to put in syntactically. I'm having a hard time finding dominate examples with html tables in general, so if anyone has good resources for that, please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used dominate, but it's generally preferable to use style sheets for css attributes (like background colour).  I would just include an external style sheet here, and give this row a certain class if it satisfies your criteria.

eg.  style.css:

```
.grey_background {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

add in a link (after the `with document(title...` line:

```
with doc.head:
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
```

finally, add the class - instead of: `l = tr()`, do something like:

```
l = tr(_class='grey_background') if row[2] == row[5] else tr()
```

**Edit: Alternatively, for an inline style**

Since it seems to support keywords, the following should work:

```
l = tr(style="background-color: grey") if row[2] == row[5] else tr()
```

Comment: This is the only thing I would need css for. Could I just keep it in the html somehow?

Comment: I tried this: `if row[2] == row[5]:l = tr(style="background-color: grey") else l=tr()`, but that gave me this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Why did you try that?  Its' a syntax error.  Why not just use the syntax I used (Python's ternary operator)?  If you like, you can break it up into 4 lines with if/else statements (or just use what I posted)?

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/429982) for how to use Python's ternary operator.